# Deleted files still in Working Directory after accepting changes from remote

Tags: git, egit

I am having trouble understanding the Git workflow.

I am using a remote git-repository which is located on Wuala-cloud-storage (similar to Dropbox, just encrypted). I clone this repository for local changes which get pushed to the remote.

Now a little example:
On computerA I created three projects A, B, and C in the lokal repo which I pushed to the remote. I cloned this remote to another computerB. Everything fine here.
Now I decided on computerA that I dont need projects B and C which I delete and push upstream again.
**Here comes the problem: I fetched (and pulled) all changes from the remote to computerB, but projects B and C are still in my working directory. When I clone the remote again to computerB then B and C are gone.**

So why are the deleted files still on the other machine, after I accepted all changes? The remote repository was created as "bare"

By the way, I am using Eclipse and the EGit-Plugin and Commandline from time to time.

Comment: The entire project or just the directories? Git doesn't track directories so they might remain. Try ```git clean -df``` to remove all untracked files/dirs.

Comment: @mateor thanks, that seems to be the problem. After I first checked the files, I had just done a "fetch" which I read somewhere is kind of a merge. Later I did a "pull" as well and was supprised to see two more changesets coming in. Probably those moved my files but kept the directories. Would you like to answer yourself, so I can award you :-)

Comment: Just did. Glad it answered the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not track directories so if they are empty that is what is happening. You can remove the dirs and other untracked files with `git clean -df`.